# Why is my content appearing outside of the screen for my app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

So I have this project where I have to make an app and I'm using html, css and jquery. Whenever I try and put content inside it always appears outside of the screen... Can anyone give any advice? When trying to run the code it won't work because you don't have access to the files but if anyone could offer advice that would be great

[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL1I4.png)

```js
$("main, section").hide(); // set display: none to main/section divs in css to stop flash

// SPLASH SCREEN //////////////////////////////////////////////

// display splash screen
$("#splash").show();

// animate on the splash screen on app load
gsap.from("#splash", {
    delay: 0.25,
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 0.5
});

// Animate Header
gsap.from("#splash header", 0.5, {
    delay: 0.5,
    y: -$("#splash header").outerHeight(),
    duration: 0.5,
    ease: "sine.out"
});

// // Animate Footer
gsap.from("#splash footer", {
    delay: 0.5,
// ! MAKE SURE YOU HAVE # FOR ID
    y: $("#splash footer").outerHeight(),
    duration: 0.5,
    ease: "sine.out"
});

gsap.from("#splash img", {
    delay: 1,
    scale: 0,
    duration: 0.5,
    ease: "back.out"
});

// wait 4 secs then fade out and load landing screen
gsap.to("#splash", {
    // ! CHANGE BACK TO 4
    delay: 2,
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 0.5,
    //! MUST COMPLETE LOAD LANDING FUNCTION
    onComplete: loadLanding
});

function loadLanding(){
    // hide and reset all screens/sections
    $("main, section").hide().css({opacity: 1});

    // ************************ SHOW ************************
    // display landing screen
    $("#landing").show();

    //  animate on the landing screen
    gsap.from("#landing", {
        delay: 0.25,
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5
    });

    gsap.from("#landing header", {
        delay: 0.5,
        y: -$("#landing header").outerHeight(),
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "sine.out"
    });

    gsap.from("#landing footer", {
        delay: 0.5,
        y: $("#landing footer").outerHeight(),
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "sine.out"
    });

    gsap.from("#logo1", {
        delay: 1,
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5
    });

    gsap.from("#logo2", {
        delay: 1.25,
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5
    });

    gsap.from("#logo3", {
        delay: 1.5,
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5
    });
}

//! Part of the landing screen but not part of the loading function
// !!!! MAKE SURE YOU MAKE YOUR LOAD REST FUNCTION!!!!
// set up logos to link to related restaurant
// pass rest ID and subnav highlight colour to loadRest function
// fade landing out and load selected restaurant

$("#logo1").click(function() {

    gsap.to("#landing", {
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5,
        onComplete: loadRest,
        // ! TWO PARAMETERS HIGHLIGHT AND ID OF RESTAURANT
        // WHICH ICON IS ACTIVE IS HEX CODE
        onCompleteParams: ["#rest1", "#0f6b37"]
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}

/**************** ADDED **************/
/* FONTS /////////////////////////////////////////////// */

/* app font */
@font-face {
  font-family: "AppFont";
  src: url(../css/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Regular.otf);
}

/* GENERAL APP STYLES /////////////////////////////////// */

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 375px;
  height: 667px;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 547px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}


/**************** Splash Screen **************/

#splash {
  background-image: url(../img/launchbg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


#splash img {
  width: 173px;
  height: auto;
}


/**************** Landing Screen **************/


#landing {
  font-family: "AppFont";
  background-image: url(../img/choicebg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 130px;
}

#cevicheLogo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}

#ballcontainer {
  margin-left: 115px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 300px;

}

.balls {
  width:15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #755A40;
  float: left;
}

#ball2 {
  opacity: .6;
}

#ball3 {
  opacity:.6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Setup HTML -->
<html dir='ltr' lang='en-ca'>
    <!-- Put metadata in head -->
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='description' content='My description of my site for search engines'>
        <meta name='viewport' content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
        

        <title>Lab-04</title>
    </head>

    <body>
     
    <!--* MENU  -->
    <main id="menu">MENU</main>
    
    
    <!--* SPLASH SCREEN FOR APP COMPANT  -->
    <main id="splash">
        <img src="img/eateries_logo_family of eateries.svg" alt="Family of Eateries" id="eaterylogo" />
    </main>
    
    <main id="landing">
        
        <!-- ! ********** ADD LANDING PAGE -->
        <!-- LANDING -->

        <div id="logo1" class="landingLogos">  
            <img id="cevicheLogo" src="img/cevichelogo.svg" alt="Ceviche" width="300" height="400" />
        </div>

        <div id="ballcontainer">
            <div id="ball1" class="balls"> </div>
            <div id="ball2" class="balls"> </div> 
            <div id="ball3" class="balls"> </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Fine Dining</h3>

        <p>Each dish is created with passion, respect and care.</p>

    </main>
```

`

Comment: Can you recreate your issue in a CodeSandbox or something? You'll have much better chances of getting an answer. I'm no expert on gasp, but I'll take a look if you can share that.

Comment: @Slbox did you see the screenshot I provided?

Comment: I did. I don't know what the problem is from the screenshot. If you want someone to help with this you're going to have to help us help you a bit more.